# gnuplot how to make the grids solid lines

Tags: gnuplot

[image]I am just learning gnuplot and I want to plot a sensor signal with a grid, but no matter what I try the grid is always dotted and I want the grid to be solid line. I try setting linetype to -1 to no avail, can someone help me?

example

```
    set grid xtics lt -1 lw 1 lc rgb "#880000"
    set grid ytics lt -1 lw 1 lc rgb "#880000"
    plot [-10:10] sin(x),atan(x),cos(atan(x))
```

Comment: Which gnuplot version and which terminal are you using? I can't reproduce this with gnuplot 5.2, or 5.4 and wxt terminal.

Comment: I am using GNUPLOT 5.4 patchlevel 4 for Windows

Comment: and which terminal? wxt, qt, pngcairo, epscairo... ?

Comment: sorry, terminal is qt

Comment: Can you please show a complete minimal script example and your resulting graph? Are you also setting a y-grid?

Comment: I just updated the initial question with a minimal script and picture of the plot. Thank you for your help

Comment: Strange. I cannot reproduce this with gnupot 5.4.4 under Windows. I get solid lines. What happens if you add a line `reset session` before these lines? And what if you replace `lt -1` with `lt 1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just uninstall and reinstall GNUPLOT again and now is working.. no idea what was the problem, but that was the fix.

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Ok, a bit a "strange" solution. But well, whatever it was... You can accept your own solution, not letting this question appear unanswered.